# Why is this code showing anomalous behaviour? (form not submitted)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form using PHP and Ajax. But the problem is that sometimes it inserts one value, sometimes 2, sometimes all, and now it is inserting nothing. Why is it happening? How can I correct it?

Here's my code:
**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "submitform.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        alert("well");
    },
    error: function(){
            alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="signupform" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <table>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required /></td>
                        <td rowspan="3"><div class="propic"><img id="imgid" src="images/dp.png" /></div>
                          <input id="imgInput" type="file" name="image"/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" required /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input id="digits" type="text" name="phone" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter your phone no." required /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="12" placeholder="Enter password" required /></td>
                        <td><input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" /></td>
                      </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "winkcage");
//$im=$_SESSION["pathsession"];
$nam=""; $usernam=""; $phon=""; $pass="";
$nam=$_POST["name"];
$usernam=$_POST["username"];
$phon=$_POST["phone"];
$pass=$_POST["password"];
$signquery="INSERT INTO signup(name, username, phone, password) VALUES('$nam', '$usernam', '$phon', '$pass')";
$signqueryrun=mysqli_query($conn, $signquery);
?>
```

NOTE: I don't want to insert image value right now. I'll insert it later when this problem is fixed.

Comment: can you show `var_dump` of `$_POST`?

Comment: I guess this PHP file is not executing right now. So I can't check it now.

Comment: check from inspect element whether the ajax is hitting specified url or is it 404 on ajax call?

Comment: Ajax is working as there's no error in Inspect element.

Comment: Check networks tab of browser's dev tools if browser is making the request.

Comment: I don't know how to do this.

Comment: At first, check form data with `console.log($("form").serialize());` before sending request

Comment: It is showing: name=asd&username=klsf&phone=324532&password=ksdf @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign your onclick to a button element, but there is no button element on your page, your button is an input element. Change that to a button and it may work. I personally would advise using ids, rather than element types, I think it makes things clearer, and will allow you to have more than one element of the same type without breaking your code.

Change

```
$("button").click(function(){
```

to

```
$("#button").click(function(){
```

and

```
data: $("form").serialize(),
```

to

```
data: $("#signupform").serialize(),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made this silly mistake, it was ID. Now it is submitting the data but the new problem is that upon clicking it is showing alert("error"). Why is it happening?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a form with a submit button, when you click the button it will submit the form. You may be having a conflict between the AJAX action and the form submit. Try preventing the default action on the button click and see if it works as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").click(function(event){
if($("form").get()[0].checkValidity()){
  $.ajax({
      url: "submitform.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: $("form").serialize(),
      success: function(data){
          alert("well");
      },
      error: function(){
              alert("Error");
              }
          });
      });
    }
    event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: What does event.preventDefault() do?

Comment: It is working now. I used ("button") instead of ("#button).

Comment: preventDefault prevents the default behavior of an element. A button (in your case an Input type="submit") has a default behavior of submitting whatever form it is in. Since you are submitting your form via AJAX, you don't want the button to submit the form. preventDefault() stops the automatic form submission.

Comment: By the way, you should also heed the advice of @Neoaptt and change your query over to PDO or at least use prepared statements in mysqli to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Oops, @randy now there's new problem. After using preventDefault(), the required attribute of inputs are not working and the empty form is being submitted. Can it be fixed?

Comment: @VikasKumar I edited my post to include checks to make sure the form is valid before AJAX submission.

Comment: What is the meaning of this: **$("form").get()[0]** ?

Answer (score 2):

You may have entered a `'` quote and it killed your sql statement. This is called [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). To prevent sql injection you can use [pdo prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). You will also want to [hash passwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to prevent people from stealling them if they get access to your database. Hashing password is a one way encryption that is easy to check.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$DB_name", $user, $pass);
$sql = "INSERT INTO signup(name, username, phone, password) VALUES(':name', ':username', ':phone', ':pass')";
if ($con = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
    $con->execute([
        ':name' => $_POST["name"],
        ':username' => $_POST["username"],
        ':phone' => $_POST["username"],
        ':pass' => $_POST["password"]
    ]);
}
```

As far as the html and javascript goes. Catch the submitted form with jquerys `.submit()` function.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(response){
            alert('complete');
        }).error(function(){
            alert('wrong');
        });
    });
```

This makes sure than any submit event triggers the ajax.